# Heroku fails to deploy Python discord bot

Tags: python, heroku

Every time i try to deploy my bot it shows me this error:

> -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
> -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
> -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
> More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
> !     Push failed

I have Procfile, requirments.txt, runtime.txt.

The requirments.txt:

> discord

The runtime.txt:

> python-3.10.3

What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple fix: the TXT file had an misspelling in the name, so I fixed it and it worked fine after that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).